# Update default name in Azure bot

Tags: azure, sharepoint, chatbot, azure-bot-service

I am new to Azure bot - I have tried to create sample Q&A chat bot. I have embed Chatbot to Sharepoint. Can someone help me how to update the default "Chat" name.

Also, I would like to see in sharepoint how can I implement functionality, so I can expand and collapse the chat window.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For this to happen usually you have to override css and JS functionality. You can find the CSS and JS file here

https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/botchat.css
https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/webchat.js

You should create your own HTML file where you can host IFRAME and these two files. Sample index.html below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <title>Web Chat: Using Web Chat v3</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <!--
      If you want to continue to use the deprecated Web Chat v3, you can use our bundle "botchat.js" or "botchat-es5.js".
      Please note that v3 does not have similar customizability and style options as in v4.
    -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/botchat.css" />
    <script src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/botchat.js"></script>
    <style>
      html,
      body {
        height: 100%;
      }
      body {
        margin: 0;
      }
      #webchat {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="webchat" role="main"></div>
    <script>
      (async function() {
        // In this demo, we are using Direct Line token from MockBot.
        // Your client code must provide either a secret or a token to talk to your bot.
        // Tokens are more secure. To learn about the differences between secrets and tokens
        // and to understand the risks associated with using secrets, visit https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0
        const res = await fetch('https://webchat-mockbot.azurewebsites.net/directline/token', { method: 'POST' });
        const { token } = await res.json();
        BotChat.App(
          {
            directLine: { token },
            user: { id: 'userid' },
            bot: { id: 'botid' },
            resize: 'detect'
          },
          document.getElementById('webchat')
        );
      })().catch(err => console.error(err));
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Reference : https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/samples/webchat-v3/

NOTE: You have to make necessary changes in JS and CSS by inspecting the browser chat window